# What's the meaning of “lead to target” in this context'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Giroir reportedly told Trump that the United States should put **“lead to target”** to stop illegal drugs from coming across the U.S.-Mexico border.

Comment: Who knows? This involves Trump.

Comment: What's the meaning of 'lead to target'?

Comment: See [this from ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324354/a-lead-to-target).

Comment: This answer is not satisfactory, can anyone explain it more clearly ?

Comment: Bullets are made mostly of lead. When they hit a target they cause damage and destruction. It's that simple.

Comment: Here lead mean ** bullets** ?

Comment: Yes, lead is gangster slang for bullets. The phrase means to just shoot suspected dealers on sight at the border. The targets are the guys bringing in the drugs.

Comment: Trump likes quirky phrasing. I'm sure he wants to imply the US should use ***live ammunition*** rather than try to fight the war on drugs using troops ***firing blanks***. Obviously part of his intention will be to ridicule those of his opponents who assume he means this ***literally*** (doubtless the *true* intended sense is effectively much more "metaphoric")

Comment: @FumbleFingers It ain't quirky. It shows a lifetime of not reading. Why even mention firing blanks? It's irrelevant.

Comment: @Lambie: Why do you keep throwing around things like *It shows a lifetime of not reading* when you know perfectly well I'm a highly articulate Lit Crit graduate? As to *It ain't quirky* - all I can do is point out that **#1** - the cited example explicitly includes "scare quotes" precisely *because* whatever hack wrote it thought that many people wouldn't be familiar with the expression, and **#2** Google Books contains *no written instances* of the sequence ***put lead to target***. I rest my case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OMG, I am talking about the red man. **Not you**. Gees. One point I would make here: Just because you can't find it with google books does not mean it can't be said or even that it's quirky. There are, it is hoped, all sorts of things in the world that have not yet been written down or even spoken. Much of the things the man says and said are not quirky at all. They are just very poorly expressed, disconnected and nonsense.

Comment: minor corrections: 1) it wasn't scare quotes, it was a direct quote. 2) it wasn't Trump who said it. Neither matter much to the question.

Comment: Anyway, it wasn't the orange man who said it. It was that guy Giroir. But the meaning is the same with or without the a. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BBC quote says "a lead to target" but all other write-ups do not include "a" in the quote. I cannot find a direct source for the statement.

If it were "a lead" (with the a) then the ELL answer seems like it is correct: lead (sounds like "Leeds") probably means "aim ahead" .

If the statement was without the leading "a", then "put lead to target" more probably uses the word "lead" as in the element *Pb* (sounds like "led"). So it means "a bullet to target" or "shoot a target with a bullet."

Comment: Does the BBC quote actually say: *put a lead to a target*?? I doubt it.

Comment: it does, actually. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-63125238

Comment: Whoops, it's that Giroir guy who said it, not the orange man. My bad. :)